# Search in LDAP with conditions?

Tags: perl, ldap

When I do

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Net::LDAP;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dn="...";
my $password="xxx";

my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new('example.com') or die "$@";
my $mesg = $ldap->bind($dn, password => $password);
if ($mesg->code) { die "uuuu $mesg"; }

$mesg = $ldap->search(
    base => "dc=example,dc=com",
    filter => "(name=LIST)",
    );

print Dumper $mesg;
```

I get

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'parent' => bless( {
                        ...
                                    }, 'Net::LDAP' ),
                 'entries' => [
                                bless( {
                                         'changes' => [],
                                         'changetype' => 'modify',
                                         'asn' => {
                                                    'objectName' => 'CN=LIST,OU=test group,OU=M,OU=I,DC=example,DC=com',
                                                    'attributes' => [
                                                                      {
                                                                        'type' => 'objectClass',
                                                                        'vals' => [
                                                                                    'top',
                                                                                    'group'
                                                                                  ]
                                                                      },
                                                                      {
                                                                        'type' => 'cn',
                                                                        'vals' => [
                                                                                    'LIST'
                                                                                  ]
                                                                      },
                                                                      {
                                                                        'type' => 'member',
                                                                        'vals' => [
                                                                                    'CN=user1,OU=BaseUsers,DC=example,DC=com',
                                                                                    'CN=user2,OU=BaseUsers,DC=example,DC=com',
                                                                                  ]
                                                                      },
                                      ...
```

where I would only like to output those from `member` that have in their object

```
objectCategory: CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Use the [GQ](http://sf.net/projects/gqclient/) LDAP client to compose and test queries.

Comment: `(objectCategory=CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com)` is a valid LDAP filter, and you can combine it with another filter using the `&` operator: `(&(filter1)(filter2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach my $entry (@{$mesg->{'entries'}})
{
    my $match = 0;
    my $name = $entry->{'asn'}->{'objectName'};

    foreach my $attr (@{$entry->{'asn'}->{'attributes'}})
    {
        if('member' eq $attr->{'type'})
        {
            foreach my $val (@{$attr->{'vals'}})
            {
                if($val =~ /^CN=.*,CN=.*,CN=.*,DC=example,DC=com$/)
                {
                    $match = 1;
                    last;
                }
            }
         }
    }

    if($match)
    {
        print $name;
    }
}
```

For your example data above this will return no matches since none of the "members" match the search pattern you specified. Also I wasn't sure if you wanted to output the object name (as per my code) or the matching string. If the latter you don't need `$match`, simply put a print in the innermost block.